# Rails SSL Local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm going through a lot of effort to get SSL working locally before I add it to my heroku app.

Is this even necessary?  I see a lot of tutorial where they are only adding it to heroku but make no mention of adding it locally.

Is there really a need?

If so do I just leave

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

and get everything working with that on both local/dev and production?

Comment: I guess it also depends if there are things that you should test before pushing it to production (for instance if certain pages should force ssl, others shouldn't). I would still recommend you to setup a staging environment on heroku with ssl and test it there instead of locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it's not necessary to set up SSL on localhost unless you absolutely need it to test certain functionality or to mirror your production environment. Requests to `localhost` aren't going to be routed over a network so there's little need for SSL in the first place. Also keep in mind Rails itself doesn't handle the SSL encryption/decryption protocol, that's the responsibility of your lower level HTTP webserver such as nginx/apache.

This would mean you should leave `config.force_ssl = false` (which is the default) unless your server is running behind SSL, as might be the case in production or staging.

Comment: okay so no real rails concerns here this is mostly with the webserver layer.  Thanks